# Problem with running web3.py code

Tags: testrpc, json-rpc, web3.py, python, web3-providers

I am trying to run this code

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import json
import pprint
import requests
from random import randint

# Debug flags
debug_transaction = False
debug_CALL_transactions = False

# Geth node parameters
rpcport = '4000'

# Experiment parameters
numBuckets = 50

# Instantiate web3
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:' + rpcport))
# Instantiate HTTP connection to Geth JSONRPC
session = requests.Session()

# Iterate over blocks and print transactions
latest = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').number

print (latest)
```

But i keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcaeb556f98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I am new to all of this. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to run the code on repl.it

Comment: The URL that you are providing is invalud, are you running a local node?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No I am not. This is a sample code I found online. I am just trying to figure out how to run it. I am new the web3.py and ethereum as a whole. How do I run a local node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have access to a node. You can access infura nodes that are freely accesible:

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/kjbuiysuidygasdy'))
web3.eth.getBlock('latest').number
```

You can get your personal key from infura that you can use instead of `kjbuiysuidygasdy` by registering for free in [Infura](https://infura.io/)

Hope this helps.